# How static resource is served by glassfish server without servlet-mapping

Tags: java, spring-mvc, glassfish, glassfish-3

I deployed war file with some static resource (.zip) on glassfish server @ physical location `{WebAppRoot}/resources/WebFiles/zippedFiles/{FileName}.zip` so for downloading/accessing file from browser relative path or URI will be `{domain.com}/resources/WebFiles/zippedFiles/{FileName}.zip`.Someday before i am trying to enable resume support for downloading such files after some Googleing i come to know that i have to tell glassfish that .zip file is an static content,so after adding

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>.zip</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Resume support is enabled.

So my question is,Before adding `<servlet-mapping>` how the .zip file is served? Is that file handled by DispatcherServlet (Dynamic content)? How the server knows URI(`{domain.com}/resources/WebFiles/zippedFiles/{FileName}.zip`) is of an file not the controller or JSP (view) for which DispatcherServlet is resposible.

And one last what is benefit of adding such `<servlet-mapping>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 'default servlet' that handles all unmapped resources.

Comment: Then before referring .zip to `<servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>` how the Webserver handling such URI request.

Comment: Because, as I already said, it handles all unmapped resources. That implies that you don't have to add a mapping for it.

Comment: okay, so what I understand is To get resume support I have to add mapping otherwise server will handle..?

Comment: If the default servlet can handle resume, I don't see why adding a mapping is required at all.

Comment: The same thing is not understood to me.. Because as you saying unmapped resources is by default handled by DefaultServlet and as per default-web.xml `useAcceptRanges` is true (which enables resume support) but still for .zip file I am getting AcceptRange hedder as `null` but after adding mapping resume support is enabled. so it means I supposed that before adding .zip is not handle by default servlet....

Comment: No it doesn't, it means that Accept-Range isn't handled by the default servlet unless it's explicitly mapped. Your inference is invalid.